# Need your thoughts on a faster approximation for the signum function I came up with.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, approximation

I recently was kind of fascinated with the whole signum function out of the blue, and was generally really curious of the already existing approximations of it. I really don't want to lag this down and before I show you mine, here are the pre-existing ones;

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{sgn(x)\approx\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+k_2^2}},\;\;\;\;\; for\;k_2 \to 0}\tag{Eq. 1}\label{1}$$
$$sgn(x)\approx tanh(kx), \;\;\;\;\; for\; k >> 1\tag{Eq. 2}\label{2}$$

These are the basic ones, and can be found at the [wikipedia page for signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). I've also looked for other sources for other approximations to this and here is what I've found;

$$sgn(x)\approx\frac{x\left(1+k\left|x\right|\right)}{1+\left|x\right|\left(1+k\left|x\right|\right)},\;\;\;\;\; x ∈ R, k ≥ 0\tag{Eq. 3}\label{3}$$
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{sgn(x)\approx\frac{e^{kx}-e^{-kx}}{e^{kx}+e^{-kx}},\;\;\;\;\; x ∈ R, k ≥ 1}\tag{Eq. 4}\label{4}$$

These two has been taken from this [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311986242_Hausdorff_approximation_of_the_sign_function_by_a_class_of_parametric_activation_functions.). Where Eq. 3 is called *Parametric Algebraic Activation (PAA) function* and Eq. 4 is called *Parametric Hyperbolic Tangent Activation (PHTA) function*. And the last one which I found is really good, is;

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid darkviolet]
{sgn(x)\approx\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{k_2}x\right),\;\;\;\;\;k_2 \to 0}\tag{Eq. 5}\label{5}$$

Unfortunately, I'm still finding the source paper for this. I'll put it soon enough (If anyone knows it, please edit it in, thank you). Here $erf$ is called the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) (also called the Gauss error function).This has been the best approximation that I could find. Now as that is over, here is my approximation;
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid darkorange]
{sgn(x)=\frac{kx}{|kx|!}||kx|-1|!, \;\;\;\;\; k≥1}\tag{Eq. 6}\label{6}$$

Now Eq. 6 is somewhat a really good approximation on its own, but Eq. 05 still beats it to a little degree. So I wanted to make another much more good expression, So I came up with this;
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{sgn(x)=\frac{k\left(x+\frac{x}{\left|kx\right|!}\right)\left(\left|\left|k\left(x+\frac{x}{\left|kx\right|!}\right)\right|-1\right|\right)!}{\left|k\left(x+\frac{x}{\left|kx\right|!}\right)\right|!}, \;\;\;\;\; k≥1}\tag{Eq. 7}\label{7}$$
Now this equation is just an extended form of Eq. 6 and is much more good.

> And when I say it is good, I meant that even for fewer values of $k$,
>   the graph of this approximation will tend to  look like this;
>
> [image].

Btw, if you're thinking why are factorials doing in Eq 6 & 7, when it is only for integers, this uses the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) (Γ) which extends the factorial function for all positive numbers as compared to the usual positive integers. Now there is one big motive to why I came up with Eq. 6; some may notice it, but as this is getting long as it is, I'm not going to explain.

And also the reason why I color-coded some of these approximations is that, I want to show them in a graphing calculator as follows. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lsb0sonxxq. I've selected some of the best approximations and my 2 approximations for comparison. And all the colored lines are as per the respective color-coded approximation that I did in this post. Here is an image of it.

[image]

For the grph-image above, I put $k=4$ for Eq $\color{black}{4}$, $\color{orange}{6}$, $\color{red}{7}$ and $k_2=4^{-1}$ for Eq $\color{blue}{1}$, $\color{darkviolet}{5}$

**FURTHERMORE**; I know that this isn't much of a question that are usually asked in here, I just wanted to know whether my methods are correct or not as I was not able to get any help elsewhere. I'm really new to complex contents of math myself. So if I did any mistake or some of these are just too obvious or things I do ignorantly, please forgive them. Any opinion, criticism, comment is really appreciated.

So what do you guys think of this? I've never seen factorial function used in any approximations. And I think my approximation is kind of a Hard-sigmoid/Saturation type of function while the others are regular Sigmoids.

Comment: I don't want to discourage your exploration of maths, but the absolute value itself is defined in terms of the signum function, i.e.
$$|x|=\frac{x}{{\rm sgn}(x)}\quad\iff\quad {\rm sgn}(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$$
so your formulas are circular since they utilize the absolute value function. Notice that the approximations in the literature use _smooth_ continuous functions like `tanh`, `erf`, `exp` precisely to avoid such circular reasoning.